# Debian security release

Tags: debian, security, docker

I have noticed that there is a "security" release listed in the Debian security tracer.

[image: releases-in-the-security-tracker]

Some of the vulnerabilities are only fixed in the "security" release, which might be still present in a different version like plain "bullseye" for example.

What exactly is the difference between plain bullseye and "bullseye (security)"?

Is there an official Docker image, where all the security patches of "bullseye (security)" are automatically included? I would like to make sure to incorporate all the stable security patches as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The bullseye (security) release refers to the most recent bullseye release with the available security patches installed.

There is apt source configured for the security patches in the official release (see the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file). The currently available security patches can be installed using apt-get, which is usually a good idea, since there might be some new patches available since the time of the last official release:

```bash
apt-get --yes update && apt-get --yes upgrade
```

which can be done in a Dockerfile as well:

```
RUN apt-get --yes update && apt-get --yes upgrade
```

After running these commands, the security patches are installed.